# Return results from lists of different type via interface c#

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have created an interface that in theory should be able to return multiple generic lists of different types to provide the client with various information. When I attempt to loop through the results of the list it is only able to return first collection, can you help me to understand how I should be returning results from the following:

Interface class:

```
public interface IExampleInterface{}

public class ExampleType : IExampleInterface
{
    public int First;
    public int Last;
}

public class ExampleAmount : IExampleInterface
{
    public decimal Amount;
    public decimal TotalFee;
}

public class ExampleFacts : IExampleInterface
{
    public bool TooLow;
    public bool TooHigh;
}
```

Interface provider:

```
public class ExampleInterfaceProvider
{
    private static readonly string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
    public static List<IExampleInterface> ExampleResults(int id) 
    {
        //declare variables, read from database query using ExecuteReader...
        var sT = new ExampleType
        {
            First = first;
            Last = last;
        }
        var sA = new ExampleAmount
        {
            Amount = amount;
            TotalFee = totalFee;
        }
        var sF = new ExampleFacts
        {
            TooHigh = tooHigh;
            TooLow = tooLow;
        }
        var exampleResults = new List<IExampleInterface> {sT, sA, sF};
        return exampleResults;
    }
}
```

On the page I need to return the data:

```
foreach (dynamic item in ExampleResults(0))
{
    Response.Write(item.First.ToString())
    Response.Write(item.Last.ToString())
    //The first two for 'sT' read fine, it breaks here
    Response.Write(item.Amount.ToString())
    //... And so on
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: you need either to cast each element to the appropriate type `ExampleType`, `ExampleAmount` ect.. or you need to give the interface a method which will be implemented in each type according to the type variables. This method you can call then on every item in your list. Also if you have your interface why do you use `dynamic`? you can use the interface as type specifier: `foreach (IExampleInterface item in ExampleResults(0))`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: why do you implement an empty interface in the first place? The interface is built to establish a contract between the datatype and the calling code(here the for loop) you should design the interface in such a way that the casting is not nesessary, otherwise the interface is useless, then you can also use simply `object` for your collection

Comment: i say dynamic should be removed and use your interface to loop then just cast each element to the appropriate type something if (item is ExampleType)( item as ExampleType).First ...etc

Comment: Keith, the error is: 'ExampleType' does not contain a definition for 'Amount'

Comment: are you using C# 7 ?

Comment: The [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) will fit.

Comment: This project uses c# 4 @Mong Zhu

Comment: I still think you should handle this with a method in the interface. Can you explain what you aim to do in the for loop? What does `Response.Write` do? Do you simply need the a couple of variables from each type as strings?

Comment: @Mong Zhu The aim is to assign the values from each type to controls on the page, or variables that will dictate what those controls display to the client, the response.Write is to test that the value returned is the correct value from code I've not included which are calculations relating to the application itself. Once the implementation of the interface is corrected the response.Write will be replaced with SomeLabel.Text = exampleType.First (as a really simple example) some types (specifically the amounts) will be formatted to currency (GBP) and displayed on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there is no another solution except comparing implementations;

```
        foreach (IExampleInterface item in ExampleResults(0))
        {
            if (item is ExampleType)
            {
                var exampleType = (ExampleType)item;
                Response.Write(exampleType.First.ToString())
                Response.Write(exampleType.Last.ToString())
            }
            else if (item is ExampleAmount)
            {
                var exampleAmount = (ExampleAmount)item;
                Response.Write(exampleAmount.Amount.ToString())
          }
            //... And so on
        }
```

If you are using C# 7, you can perform it as `switch case`

```
        foreach (IExampleInterface item in ExampleResults(0))
        {
            switch (item)
            {
                case ExampleType c:
                    Response.Write(c.First.ToString());
                    Response.Write(c.Last.ToString());
                    break;
                case ExampleAmount c:
                    Response.Write(c.Amount.ToString());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            //... And so on
        }
```

You can find the [documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/10/16/dissecting-the-pattern-matching-in-c-7/).

Answer (score 1):

So basically, the items implementing `IExampleInterface` should all be written to a `Response` in a way that is somewhat specific to the actual type implementing the interface?

Then how about this:

```
public interface IExampleInterface
{
    void WriteTo(Response response);
}

public class ExampleType : IExampleInterface
{
    public int First;
    public int Last;

    public void WriteTo(Response response)
    {
        response.Write(First.ToString());
        response.Write(Last.ToString());
    }
}

public class ExampleAmount : IExampleInterface
{
    public decimal Amount;
    public decimal TotalFee;

    public void WriteTo(Response response)
    {
        response.Write(Amount.ToString());
        response.Write(TotalFee.ToString());
    }
}

public class ExampleFacts : IExampleInterface
{
    public bool TooLow;
    public bool TooHigh;

    public void WriteTo(Response response)
    {
        response.Write(TooLow.ToString());
        response.Write(TooHigh.ToString());
    }
}
```

And then:

```
foreach (IExampleInterface item in ExampleResults(0))
{
    item.WriteTo(Response);
}
```

Assuming that `Response` is a variable holding an instance of the response rather than a static class.